# angular js todo list not showing up

Tags: javascript, angularjs

trying beginner's Angular using tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuiHuZq_cg4. i think files are in proper places, permissions set, yet my index.html shows nothing on my browser, and Chrome dev tools show everything in place, no errors. code is here" https://gist.github.com/9ad771c60d33fc020216.git, but also here: [what am i missing??]

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0rc3/angular-1.0.0rc3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/todo.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controllers="TodoCtrl">
  {{totalTodos}}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

todo.js:

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.totalTodos = 4;
}
```

Comment: u using a server to host that page?

Comment: You wrote "ng-controllers", with an s

Comment: hi, Tim - i used gist.github to post code publically, for sharing, if that is what you mean. otherwise, am not hosting the code on any other server. let me know if that did not answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ng-controller="TodoCtrl"
```

instead of

```
ng-controllers="TodoCtrl"
```

S won't tag with controller